# Simplify $a^2(y-3)+a(3-y)+7(y-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I got the question $a^2(y-3)+a(3-y)+7(y-3)$ on my homework but I'm not sure how to start to solve it. Do I group the two $(y-3)s$ together or factor a $-1$ out of $(3-7)$ or something entirely different? 
Some pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take out common factor $y-3$ to get $$a^2-a+7$$

Comment: But what about the (3−y) left over?

Comment: Just replace $(3-y)$ by $-(y-3)$. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $3-y=-(y-3)$ and so
$$\begin{align}a^2(y-3)+a(3-y)+7(y-3)&=a^2(y-3)-a(y-3)+7(y-3)\\
&=(a^2-a+7)(y-3)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

This makes a lot more sense now.